# CSS rules do not work in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a registration form where this CSS rules apply. when user submits with incorrect or empty data in some required fields, we highlight the error field by a RED BORDER around the error field. This is not working in IE. The RED Border appears in FF and safari.

I have a code like this:

```css
#errorMsg {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    background:#FEE !important; 
    border:1px solid #C33; 
    color:#C33 !important; 
    font-size:110%; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin: 20px 0; 
    padding:15px; 
    text-align:left;
}

.parentError {
    background: #FEE; 
    border: 1px solid #C33; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    left: -10px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 0px; 
    width: 635px;
}

[type=text].elementError, 
[type=password].elementError,
select.elementError {
    border: 2px solid #C33;
}
```

It works in Firefox 8 and Safari, but not in IE 8.

I am novice in CSS. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: But **what part of this css** is not working as expected in IE ?

Comment: I have a registration form where this CSS rules apply. when user submits with incorrect or empty data in some required fields, we highlight the error field by a RED BORDER around the error field. This is not working in IE. The RED Border appears in FF and safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE you can decide which css you want to present. You can also decide to present different css in different versions of IE.

You can Create an IE-Only Stylesheet

Example:

Target IE 8 and HIGHER:

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This code will operate only in IE 8 and higher. means that you can create css file for 8 and higher. and a different file for lower version then 8.

This is just an example. This method give you a lot of power.

You can see this [link](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

Comment: I did this and i think it is helpful. Now i want to highlight the errors but giving some indication to the user.. How can I do that?

Comment: say i have a text field First name which is left empty by the user, which is a required field. Now I want the user to get to notice that by Highlighting. IN FF, i am able to highlight that by drawing RED Box around the Text field with the above code. What are the other ways i can try in IE?

Comment: you want that the user notice the text field after he enter the submit button?

Answer (score 1):

IE8 don't have support for CSS3 elements like -moz-border-radius, -webkit-border-radius. But FF8 and Safari both support CSS3 elements. that's why CSS3 works in FF8 and safari.

You can also check the current implementation of  CSS3 Modules statuses at http://www.css3.info/modules/

Also you can view the [browser compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) here .

Comment: @user1254174 You can check this library http://css3pie.com/ . It supports many CSS3 features for IE6,7,8 and IE9

Comment: Thanks that is useful.  I need permission from my superiors before i can install PIE and try that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the very start of your HTML document:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Without it, or some other doctype declaration of a specific kind, IE works in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html). This means, among other things, that it does not recognize many CSS features such as attribute selectors (like `[type=text]`).

For robustness, to work even on IE 6 (which does not recognize attribute selectors in any mode), consider using simpler selectors like `input.elementError` and assign the class `elementError` to such `input` elements only for which you want that styling.

Comment: we have this already in the first line of HTML.                                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">                             I tried input.elementError but it still doesn't work in IE 8 for me.

Comment: I am able to apply elementError to the Inputs and select fields as required but                                           input.elementError, select.elementError { border: 2px solid #C33; }         doesn't work. Any work around for this in IE..

Comment: @user1254174, the style sheet works fine in IE. There is something else on your page that causes the problem. Please post the code of a full document, or a URL of a full document, that exhibits the problem.

Comment: You were right some thing was not working in the background before applying CSS rules. I have corrected it now. Now i am able to get all input fields highlighted but not the select dropdowns. You can see the web application at [link]www.livetext.com -> register and purhcase -> register membership ->student-> Enter 16 digit random no-> submit the form by clicking "Register My membership account" at the bottom of the page

Comment: @user1254174, exactly what is wrong? I cannot see any `select` element with `class=parentError` on the page, though there are `select` elements inside `div` elements with that class. There is a `div` element with `class="grey parentError"` and it seems that for it, the background color set for the `grey` class wins. Please be exact in describing what you expect to happen and what you see instead.

Comment: If you can open the same in FF8 and also in IE8, you can see the difference after the Improper submit.                class=parentError applies only for the DIVs.                         Css:                                                  `select.elementError {
    border: 2px solid #C33;
}`                                                                  HTML:                                                                <SELECT id=grad_month **class=elementError** tabIndex=251 name=grad_month>.... </SELECT>

Comment: If you can open the same in FF8 and also in IE8, you can see the difference after the Improper submit.                class=parentError applies only for the DIVs.                         Css:                                                                `select.elementError {
    border: 2px solid #C33;
}`                                                                  HTML:                                                                <SELECT id=grad_month **class=elementError** tabIndex=251 name=grad_month>.... </SELECT>. _select.elementError_ IS **not** getting applied in IE8.

Comment: this is the css rule which i have now `input.elementError, select.elementError { border: 2px solid #C33; }`

Comment: @user1254174, I’m not sure whether the page has changed, but at least now the problem appears to be with the tag
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`
near the start of the document. It throws IE to IE 7 mode, in which border properties are not applied to `select` elements.